# Problem with automatic numbering of values for logarithmic plotting, e.g., 0.00 substituted for 0.01

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

On the figure below, notice the value 0.00 automatically generated for the largest y-axis value, where the correct number would be 0.01, or $1.\times10^{-2}$. I think this has more to do with an improper transition between number formats, i.e., a bug in the source code, than anything to do with the particulars of code I used to create the graph, as I did not specify any tick operations and the axes scales were default generated.

[image]

So, my question is simple. **Is this a Mathematica source code bug in 12.2?**

**EDIT** I have been asked for the code. I do not believe the code is especially relevant, the only relevance I think is the scaling of the y-axis. **This problem occurs infrequently** and I have been seeing it approximately 1% of the time. In version 13 this same code problem did not occur for this particular case not because the bug has been fixed necessarily, but because the default axis numbering is less frequent:
[image]

```
fixLogPlots[gr_]:=gr/.f:(Charting`ScaledTicks|Charting`ScaledFrameTicks)[{Log,Exp}]:>(Part[#,;;, ;;3]&@*f);
show1=fixLogPlots@ListLogLogPlot[{Transpose[{Flatten[tdat],Flatten[y]}]},Joined->{False},PlotRange->{{0.8Min[tdat],100},{kall \[Beta]^\[Alpha] \[Alpha]  100.`65^(-1-\[Alpha]),2kall GPC[Min[tdat]]}},PlotMarkers->{Graphics[{Thickness[.18`65],Black,Circle[{0,0},0.05`65]},ImageSize->8,ImagePadding->All],"",""},(*PlotStyle\[Rule]{Directive[Thick,Darker[Green],Opacity[0.7]],Directive[Thick,Blue]},*)ImageSize->{500,500/GoldenRatio},PlotRangePadding->0,Frame->{True,True,False,False},FrameStyle->{Directive[Thick,Black,18],Directive[Thick,Black,18]},FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Thick,Black,18],FrameLabel->{"Time (hours)","Concentration (mg/ml)"}];
show2=fixLogPlots@LogLogPlot[{kall GPC[t],kall \[Beta]^\[Alpha] \[Alpha]  t^(-1-\[Alpha])},{t,0.9Min[tdat],100},PlotRange->{{0.8Min[tdat],100},{kall \[Beta]^\[Alpha] \[Alpha]  100.`65^(-1-\[Alpha]),2kall GPC[Min[tdat]]}},PlotStyle->{Directive[Thick,Blue],Directive[Thick,Darker[Green],Opacity[0.7]],Directive[Thick,Blue]}];
Print[Show[show1, show2]];
```

Finally, the data tdat and y consist of 11 coordinate pairs, and the GPC function is user defined as per https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs10928-021-09779-4/MediaObjects/10928_2021_9779_MOESM1_ESM.nb

with parameters
a=0.5392732426550947315098442595080049054694776627358212768959880081;
b=0.1774139953426106794374503679271139251361516553812610871497077734;[Beta]->0.0063857263654692926149893968293647889981814795161761111564951576825;
[Alpha]=1.5638116785544485252563062847275140590587112618712466081403870969;
kall=0.041008313217569595198376814150827514314887213856212188062953699539;

Comment: Can we please see the Mathematica code that has generated this plot?

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other users have confirmed the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER BUT RATHER AN EXTENDED COMMENT**

The linked notebook in the OP does not handle precision as you expect. For example,

```
a = N[Rationalize[0.34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616], 65];
```

`a` is identical to the original input value

```
a === 0.34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616

(* True *)
```

If you enter at least `Ceiling[$MachinePrecision + 1]` digits, the number is interpreted as an arbitrary-precision number with the given precision (see [`Numerical Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#21155))

Further, [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) with the default tolerance does not `Rationalize` a high precision input.

```
Rationalize[0.\
34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616]

(* 0.34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616 *)
```

However `Rationalize[x, 0]` will convert any inexact number to rational form.

```
Rationalize[0.\
34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616, 0]
```

[image]

Compare

```
a // FullForm
```

[image]

with

```
(a = N[Rationalize[
     0.34931003807815571524792421542558602868248355919027496611955665616, 0], 
    65]) // FullForm
```

[image]

The extra digits help to maintain the precision but the precision is tracked as `65.`

Comment: Thanks for that. Writing new functions is thankless, and any comments are very welcome.

Comment: Gave you a +1 for helpfulness even if it helps on something other than the question itself. Any clues on the question?

Comment: Thanks for the vote; however, unless you post an example of complete consolidated code that reproduces the problem, I am not going to spend time on it.

Comment: You are welcome, but the error is inconsistent, and being as I upgraded to V 13 the particular case error has disappeared. To give you another example, I would have to generate random scaled plots and search somehow for that particular annoying bug, and on your platform you would likely have to do the same to find it in a possibly different plot.

Comment: Also, the program in which it appears is large, If you want to see it, I can copy it into a notebook by itself, but don't know how to attach that here. Also, if you rerun it, the error may disappear as mentioned.